# Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) - $this->url()->toRoute()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

The function `return $ this-> redirect() ->toRoute('home');` redirect to my home page.
The function `return $ this-> redirect() ->toRoute('home', array('controller' => 'index',                     'action' =>  'hello'));` must redirect at HomePage/index/hello but the redirection is juste HomePage.

```
'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '[/:controller][/:action][/:id]'
```

What is my error ?

Tks

Comment: More like `IndexController#helloAction()`.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your route configuration so we can get some context, atm it's unclear where exactly the snippet you've posted fits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the `index` Controller and `hello` action as default? Then they are not displayed in the URL but the right page will shown.